# Why does Kube State Metrics require cluster-scoped read operations on Secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-prometheus-stack

We have installed Kube prometheus stack on our kubernetes cluster and I noticed that the clusterRole "kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics" has the resource "secrets" with verbs "list, watch".

As a central Kubernetes management team in an organization, we would like to give restricted access for Secrets, and just wanted to get an idea around what's the use-case which the operator is supporting.

Why does it need cluster wide access to secrets?

Answer (score 0):

Kube-prometheus uses kube-state-metrics as part of the stack.
By default, kube-state-metrics enable the secrets in the objects to be enabled by default during the default installation.

Check this

- [Manifest of deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/98b38ba9bbfdff27b359c58adecab30cc1311a78/examples/daemonsetsharding/deployment.yaml#L25)
- [CLI arguments](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/98b38ba9bbfdff27b359c58adecab30cc1311a78/docs/cli-arguments.md?plain=1#L66)

Comment: But does it need the permission to read secrets or is it there because they just put everything?